# What is "temporal depth"?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, terminology, papers, action-recognition

I need some explanation about the following paragraph (page 3) from the paper [A Novel Approach for Robust Multi Human Action Detection and Recognition based on 3-Dimentional Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1907/1907.11272.pdf).

> We introduce a 3D convolution neural network with the following notations: $I(x, y, d)$ as an input video with a size of $x y$ and $d$ the temporal depth

What is "temporal depth"? Is it the number of frames?

Answer (score 1):

Temporal Depth is a third parameter of a time series data. For example if you have a video clip of length 25 frames and on training a model you are giving first five frames with respect to time. Your temporal depth will be 5.